# How do I get a ROM onto my ICS (Android 4.0) tablet?

Tags: usb, rom-flashing, rom, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a Galaxy Tablet 10.1. I decided to root it, that went fine. Then I decided to upgrade to Ice Cream Sandwich. That also went fine.

It was only after upgrading that I discovered the camera does not work (yes, the warnings were there, but they weren't made very obvious). That sucks, so I wanted to go back down to an earlier version. I seem to have lost the ROM for my earlier version on the tablet, so I went to copy it back to my tablet, thinking that would be simple...

But ICS doesn't let me connect to my computer via USB.

After looking around the web, this is apparently because of a change in the way ICS is going to handle USB connectivity, which is an issue I don't want to embed myself into. All I know is I want to get out of ICS and back to Honeycomb.

How can I get the ROM onto my tablet so that I can install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably tons of ways to do this, but here's what I can think of offhand:

- If you have `adb` set up on your computer then use it to push the ROM file over: `adb push /path/to/ROM /sdcard`
- Upload it to [Dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5kcm9wYm94LmFuZHJvaWQiXQ..), [Box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.box.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5ib3guYW5kcm9pZCJd), or any other cloud file storage service and then download it via the associated Android app
- Upload it to a file sharing service like Mediafire and then download it in your browser
- If you downloaded the ROM from somewhere, visit that site in the browser on your tablet and download it directly
- Install a file manager or other app that supports FTP and send it over via a wifi LAN connection ([one example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3Ryb25ncy5hbmRyb2lkLnBvcCJd))
- Try [Kies Air](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.swift.app.kiesair&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zYW1zdW5nLnN3aWZ0LmFwcC5raWVzYWlyIl0.) - I think it supports wireless file transfer